# How to determine which part of an nsstring fits into a rect?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, uikit, core-graphics, pdf-generation

This is about PDF formatting using core graphics. 
But it could be about any type of paging when it comes to printing a string on two pages.

I need to spread a string over several pages. For smaller strings this is no real problem. For those I use the NSString UIKit extensions `sizeWithFont` to determine, whether the full text fits on the current page or not. If it does, then I print it with `drawInRect` and if it does not then I move it to the next page.

Works fine but is not suitable for longer strings. In my app individual strings (provided by the user) may even be longer than a full page.

When there is a full page or some remaining space of a page given, how do I determine exactly what part of the NSString can be displayed in that given rect so that I can cut it off and print the remaining string (or at least a part of it) on the next page?

I thought of an alternative. That is drawing the full text into an off screen graphics context and then cut the created image into slices which fit into the free space on the pages. But if I do that then I need to place the cutting line exactly between the text lines. And frankly I am not sure how to figure out where the text containing graphic can be safely cut into two (or more) parts without cutting a line of text in its middle.

I hope I expressed myself understandable and that somebody comes to the rescue.

Comment: +1, Finally someone clearly articulating this confounding conundrum.

Comment: I doubt you really want to do this using your alternative... If this was about bitmap imaging, Ok, but you surely don't want your text included in your PDF as bitmap...

Comment: @mkl, you are right. That is why I am asking. However, in the end I need a pdf that prints perfectly layouted on paper. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Core Text, there is [a very relevant function](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Carbon/Reference/CTFramesetterRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints), whose last argument (a pointer to a CFRange) is defined as follows:

> `fitRange`
>
> On return, contains the range of the string that actually fit in the constrained size.

Comment: Apologies for the late response. I had to put this project aside right after asking this question due to priorities. Now that I continue workint on it I found that your suggestion, or the linked one, works perfectly right. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Hi hermann I am also facing the same issue. But I am creating the PDF file using UIKit methods and by using 
favorite
Hi in my application I have to generate PDF file by getting data from an Array.Pdf generation is done successfully using UIKit methods like drawrect and by using

UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(thefilePath, CGRectZero, nil);

UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, pageSize.width, pageSize.height), .Here I cannnot able to decide length of string that can fit in any row and the remaining string in another row in next page.Please can you explain how you used fit range.

Comment: @Naresh: I think you should ask a new question that explains what you're doing and the problem you're having in more detail.

Answer (score 2):

For the general case where you are not using Core Text, you can just keep adding characters to the string until its size is too large. This can be quite fast, and if you have really enormous strings (as you seem to), you can speed it up with a simple binary search.

If you're using Core Text, just create a `CTFrame` for the area you want to fill and then ask it for the range it used with `CTFrameGetVisibleStringRange()`.

Comment: Rob and Peter, I will certainly have a look at core text. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How about using an approximation?

```
- (NSInteger)lengthOfString:(NSString *)str
           thatFitsIntoView:(UIView *)displayView
                   withFont:(UIFont *)font
{
    CGSize textSize = [str sizeWithFont:font
                               forWidth:displayView.frame.size.width
                          lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

    NSInteger lengthThatFits;
    if (textSize.height > displayView.frame.size.height) {
        lengthThatFits = str.length * displayView.frame.size.height / textSize.height;
    } else {
        lengthThatFits = str.length;
    }

    return lengthThatFits;
}
```

Call it like:

```
NSString *str = @"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin eros"
    "nulla, commodo eget fringilla nec, varius nec ligula. Donec pulvinar eros sed diam"
    "euismod scelerisque. Mauris imperdiet leo at elit vulputate ullamcorper. Nullam"
    "condimentum odio a lacus tempus ac pretium justo tincidunt.";

UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0]; // or whatever
UIView *displayView = // the view in which you intend to present the string

NSInteger length = [self lengthOfString:str thatFitsIntoView:displayView usingFont:font];
NSString *displayedString = [str substringToIndex:length];
```

Comment: Yes, if I don't find anything better then I would have to go for an approximation. An approximation would need to take line/word wrapping into consideration. I might then even to "sentence wrapping". Meaning I would cut the string only after full stops ".", semicolons etc. And then test the part of the string whether it really fits into the rect. But that would depend on the user making reasonalbe input. Your suggestion would fail if the user enters a significant number of cr/lf. I need something more accurate. Some `numberOfCharsOfString:fitIntoRect:withFont:lineBreakMode:` or so.

Comment: @HermannKlecker This does exactly that. Returns the number of characters that fit in. You can fine tune the result by starting an iteration from `lengthThatFits` back towards 0 and test if the substring until that index fits.

Comment: I appreciate your assistance. But I doubt that it does exactly hat. First it determines the height of the text block the usual way. Then it checks whether the text block would fit on the page. Fine so far. But then it just takes the relation of the full text height to the size of the free space on the page and multiplies that relation with the number of characters and returns that result. (cont ...)

Comment: Even if the string contains of lots of "a" only, 11 rows of "aaaa...". Lets say 50 a's in each line and 550 a's in total so that the text makes up to 11 lines of "aaaa..." Your solution woult then return 275. But the a number 275 is in the middle of line 6 and only the upper half of line 6 would fit into the page. See? And that does not even take any word wrapping into consideration or lines that ony consist of cr/lf which would totally screw up this calulation if they are not taken into consideration.

Comment: @HermannKlecker That's why I suggested the method involving some iteration for fine-tuning. That way you could be sure you get back the text that really fits.

Comment: Yes, some smart step by step getting closer approach could do the trick.