# How to get a string of a particular height in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

Hi in my application I have a lengthy string. From that string I have to substring a part of a string where the string height to be 500. So please let me know how to get the a part of a string.

For your reference I am sharing the code what I used for getting string height

```
 CGSize finalStringSize = [finalString sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(195,length) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
```

Here finalstringSize.height is 500. Now any one help me to get a substring from final string where that substring height to be 500.

Please help me.

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to get the substring that will fit inside the field? Can you explain a little more about what you are actually trying to achieve.

Comment: Yes I have to get substring but here I cannot able to decide the  exact length of a string to determine range of substring.

Comment: I'm sure someone out there knows of a more elegant solution but you could perform a loop each time eliminating one character from the string until you reach the desired height...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code for set particular content height:

```
 NSString *finalString=@"d jdsfhksd fsdfhjkds fkdhsfjkdsf kdsfhjkdsf sdjkfsdfh dsfhsfisudi udsifhisdhf sdhfkh sdkf dshf ksdh fkhsd khsdfh sdkhf sdhkfhsdjkfhdshf sdfhdshf hsdfh ksdhf kdhsf hsdkfhsdkhf sdf hsdkfh dsf sdkhf ksdhf hsdfh sdhfksdhf sd ksdhsdh ksdh dhs hsdh ksdh dhs fhsdfh dsfsdfdf sdf sd sd dsf sd fsdf ds"; 
 int length =200; 
 UIFont *font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:17.0f]; 
 NSString *firstPartString=[NSString stringWithString:finalString]; 

 CGSize firstPartStringSize = [firstPartString sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(195,MAXFLOAT) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping]; 

 while(firstPartStringSize.height > length) 
 { 
      firstPartString = [firstPartString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, firstPartString.length-1)]; 
      firstPartStringSize = [firstPartString sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(195,MAXFLOAT) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping]; 
 } 

 if(firstPartStringSize.height <= length) 
 { 
      while(![[firstPartString substringToIndex:[firstPartString length]-1] isEqualToString:@" "]) 
      { 
           NSLog(@"%@",[firstPartString substringFromIndex:[firstPartString length]-1]); 
           if([firstPartString substringFromIndex:[firstPartString length]-1].length !=0 && ![[firstPartString substringFromIndex:[firstPartString length]-1] isEqualToString:@" "]) 
           { 
                firstPartString = [firstPartString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, firstPartString.length-1)]; 
           } 
           else 
           { 
                break; 
           } 

      } 
 } 

 NSString *resultStr=firstPartString; 

 int secondPartStringLength=[finalString length]-firstPartString.length; 
 NSRange secondPartStringRange=NSMakeRange(firstPartString.length, secondPartStringLength); 
 NSString *secondPartString=[finalString substringWithRange:secondPartStringRange];
```

Comment: I have tested above code in my application with static string and it's work perfect

Comment: This is a (less efficient) repeat of the 1st answer. What's the point of the `stringWithFormat:` call?

Comment: than what is the more efficient?

Comment: 1) Your answer is a duplicate of the earlier answer. 2) You needlessly call `stringWithFormat:`. Get rid of that whole line. 3) You create a new font every loop iteration. Why?

Comment: Check both's if condition it's not duplicate

Comment: Very good. I missed that detail. Your `if` statement is more correct.

Comment: @Naresh check my updated code... SecondStr gives you the string which you want to write in second page of pdf... Means remaining string after setting with your  height.

Comment: Hi I updated my question with screenshot. Here the text is spliting in two pages but at end of text in first page the text is not word wrapped.Can you please let me know how can we handle this issue.

Comment: ok i got it... i had created the pdf report with same requirement

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41681/discussion-between-pradhyuman-chavda-and-naresh)

Comment: @Naresh hey buddy let's chat about your problem

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment, you can try this:

```
CGSize finalStringSize = [finalString sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(195,length) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
while( finalStringSize.height > 500 ){
    finalString = [finalString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, finalString.length-1)];
    finalStringSize = [finalString sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(195,length) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
}
NSLog(finalString); // and that is your end string...
```

As per your comment below, you can use `CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints` method to find the `NSRange` that you can use in `[finalString substringWithRange:range];` to get your final result.

Documentation for that method is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Carbon/Reference/CTFramesetterRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CTFramesetterSuggestFrameSizeWithConstraints).

Comment: Hi Goran thanks for your reply.But it won't work it out for me.

Comment: What is the problem, I didn't have a chance to test this code... can you explain the result you are getting? infinite loop? what is the finalStringSize you are getting?

Comment: Hi Goran Actually my concern is I want to know the string length that will fit in a particular rect.This is my requirement I want to know the length that will fit in a rect.Can you please help me in this concern.

Comment: Hi Goran actually for know the issue what I am facing please check this question.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15321544/how-to-determine-which-part-of-an-nsstring-fits-into-a-rect. Here I am creating the PDF using UIKit methods not core graphics.

Comment: @Naresh This answers your question. After the loop, `finalString` is the string that fits in the rectangle. If you want the length then call `finalString.length`.

Comment: using finalString.length he will get total length width not height. And he is asking for height

Comment: @PradhyumanChavda The OP wants to know the final length of the string that fits in the rect that is 500 points tall. `finalString.length` does not give a width, it gives the final string length, in characters.

Comment: @Naresh does this answer your question?

Comment: Hi Goran it's not clear to me. Can you come for chat. There I can explain my issue very clearly. pls

Comment: Sure, send me an invite.

Comment: Hi Goran I got man. Finally My issue is get resolved. Thanks a lot Goran.

Comment: Hi goran I have one more doubt shall you can come for chat.

Comment: Hi goran I don't know how to send a invitation for chat can you please a invitation for chat.