# Creating additional pages in a PDF from Core Data Information

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, text

Currently, I have a working system which generates happily a PDF page with a border, header and Core Data information populating the entire PDF. It works really well, except for when I have more records than can fit on the page. Rather than automatically creating a new page, it's just going off the page.

I'd really appreciate any insight into how I can automatically create a second page (with the same border, header, etc) from the first page to take care of the additional data.

My code for creating the text, border and header is below:

```
- (void) drawLine
{
    CGContextRef    currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetLineWidth(currentContext, kLineWidth);

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(currentContext, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);

    CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(kMarginInset + kBorderInset, kMarginInset + kBorderInset + 40.0);
    CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(pageSize.width - 4*kMarginInset -4*kBorderInset, kMarginInset + kBorderInset + 40.0);

    CGContextBeginPath(currentContext);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(currentContext, startPoint.x, startPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(currentContext, endPoint.x, endPoint.y);

    CGContextClosePath(currentContext);
    CGContextDrawPath(currentContext, kCGPathFillStroke);
}

- (void) drawBorder
{
    CGContextRef    currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    UIColor *borderColor = [UIColor brownColor];

    CGRect rectFrame = CGRectMake(kBorderInset, kBorderInset, pageSize.width-kBorderInset*2, pageSize.height-kBorderInset*2);

    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(currentContext, borderColor.CGColor);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(currentContext, kBorderWidth);
    CGContextStrokeRect(currentContext, rectFrame);
}

- (void) drawText
{

     NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];

     NSFetchRequest *pdfFetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
     NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Transaction" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
     pdfFetchRequest.entity = entity;

     NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"dates.dateOfEvent" ascending:NO];

     pdfFetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sort];
     pdfFetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20;

     pdfFetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"whoBy = %@", self.person];

     NSError *error = nil;
     NSArray *types = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:pdfFetchRequest error:&error];


    CGContextRef    currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(currentContext, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];

    CGSize textSize = CGSizeMake(pageSize.width - 5*kBorderInset-5*kMarginInset, pageSize.height - 5*kBorderInset - 5*kMarginInset);

    CGRect renderingRect = CGRectMake(kBorderInset + kMarginInset, kBorderInset + kMarginInset + 50.0, pageSize.width - 2*kBorderInset - 2*kMarginInset, textSize.height);



    for (Transaction *trans in types)
    {


        if ([types count] == 1)
        {
            NSString *amount = trans.item.amount; 
            NSString *occasions = trans.occasion.title;
            NSString *textToDraw = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Occasion = %@, Amount = %@ ", occasions, amount];

            [textToDraw drawWithRect:renderingRect options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:font} context:nil];

        }

        if ([types count] > 1)
        {
            NSString *amount = trans.item.amount; 
            NSString *occasions = trans.occasion.title;
            NSString *textToDraw = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Occasion = %@, Amount = %@ ", occasions, amount];

            renderingRect.origin.y += 50.0;

            [textToDraw drawWithRect:renderingRect options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:font} context:nil];
        }
    }
}
```

So there are two questions with this:

1) How do I have the PDF create a second page when the text reaches a certain height in the PDF page? I figure I have to create an incrementing number of some sort but I have no idea what I'd do and how I'd do it!

2) If the Core data has one entry, it starts at the top. If it has two or more entries, it starts at a position 50.0 below. I understand why that is happening because I implemented it that way, but how do I get the text to appear at the top, even if it's more than 1 entry.

Any thoughts on this would be massively appreciated.

Comment: can you provide me the whole code for create pdf?

Comment: Check this one I hope this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20136703/how-to-get-a-string-of-a-particular-height-in-objective-c/20137347#20137347

Answer (score 0):

Ad.1 `if (ypos >= maxY) {
               // create a new page and reset the current page's Y value
               UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, pageSize.width, pageSize.height), nil);
               ypos=30;
}`